What is the surname of Vaishyas?
Brahmins are Sharma
Kshatriyas are Varma
What are the vedic surnames of Vaishyas and Shudras?

Guptha and Dhasa afaik

I dont think sudras are known as dasas. Do you have any scriptural proof?

If I had I would have written an answer. Afaik its found in Manusmruthi.
